# Guess and verify: verification theorem for Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation

Tags: optimal-control, dynamic-programming

Let $t \in [0,\infty)$ denote time, $x(t) \in X \subset \mathbb R_+$ the state and $u(t) \in \mathbb R_+$ the control.
Consider the following optimal control Problem
\begin{align}
&V(x_0) = \max_{u(t)}\int_0^\infty{e^{-rt}\ln(u(t))dt}\\[2mm]
\text{s.t.} \quad &\dot x(t) = -u(t) \tag{O}\\
&x_0 = x(0) > 0.
\end{align}
where $r > 0$.
I claim that the feedback law $\phi(x(t)) = rx(t)$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$ is the optimal solution.

**Proposition**
There exists an optimal solution for (O) characterized by
\begin{align}
&V(x) = \frac{1}{r}(\ln(rx) - 1),\\
&\phi(x) = rx.
\end{align}

- How can I prove that?

I know that $\phi(x)$ must satisfy the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman (HJB) equation for all $x \in X$
\begin{align}
rV(x) =& \max_{u}\{\ln(u) - V'(x)u\}\\
=& \ln\left(\frac{1}{V'(x)}\right) - 1\\
=& \ln(rx) - 1.
\end{align}
Check.
I also know that the transversality condition
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-rt}V(x(t)) = 0 
\end{align}
must be satisfied.
The solution of $\dot x(t) = -rx(t)$ is given by
\begin{align}
x(t) = x_0e^{-rt}.
\end{align}
It follows 
\begin{align}
&\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-rt}V(x(t))\\
=&\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-rt}\frac{1}{r}(\ln(r x_0e^{-rt})-1)\\
=&\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\ln(r x_0) - rt - 1}{e^{rt}r}\\
=&\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{r}{e^{rt}r^2}\\
=&0.
\end{align}
Check.
Are we done? Is this procedure sufficient to show that $\phi(x)$ is indeed optimal?